# Dojo.query remove class

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to remove a class so I use this following code :

```
var StyleToRemove = query(".someclass").parent().parent().parent().parent(); 
StyleToRemove.forEach(function(node) {
    domClass.remove(node, "ui-state-default");
});
```

The code works on Firefox(StyleToRemove returns object HTMLdivElement) but not on ie8(StyleToRemove returns object).

Why ?

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't even need to manually iterator over the `NodeList` that `query` returns.  You can require in the "dojo/NodeList-dom" dependency and dojo will automatically add a "removeClass" method to the NodeList class.

```
require(['dojo/query', 'dojo/NodeList-dom'], function (query, nodelistDom) {
    query('#x').removeClass('myClass');
});
```

I made a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACvty/) demonstrating this.